# Set param validation in the constructor template in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I often find myself to automatically generate a constructor using fields in eclipse, so that it will turn this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyObject object;
    private String myString;
}
```

into this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyObject object;
    private String myString;

    public MyClass(MyObject object, String myString) {
        this.object = object;
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change eclipse templates to make it generate a constructor that null-validates the parameters? Like this

```
public MyClass(MyObject object, String myString) {
    if (object == null || myString == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    this.object = object;
    this.myString = myString;
}
```

Comment: How would I change it? Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

The command **Generate Constructor using Fields ...** hard-codes the strategy for creating the constructor body. Only the javadoc is generated using templates (which can be edited via the preference Java > Editor > Templates).

It should, however, be possible to write your own template proposal that *inserts* the desired null checks *into an existing constructor*, which would make the task you are asking about a two step action: (1) create constructor using fields & (2) add parameter null checks.
See [Help > Java development user guide > Concepts > Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-editor-templates.htm?cp=25_2_6) for creating your own templates.

BTW, it seems you are not using [null annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm&cp=25_3_9_0) to let the compiler inform you, which parameters need to be null-checked and which don't, are you?